# What’s the right way to implement a symbol drawing library in HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am porting a symbol drawing library from Java to Javascript. The symbols will be drawn into an HTML5 Canvas object. Symbols have coordinates and the properties of shape (square, circle, cross,etc…), size, and color.

I have had such a working symbol drawing library in Java for many years. In Javascript, I’m having a hard time with color. Symbols are usually drawn with the correct shape and size but not always with the right color. The color from one symbol can also “bleed” to other things, like chart axes, that I’m drawing (usually in black). So how do I make drawing a symbol an “atomic” unit of drawing so there are no side effects on other things I’m drawing? I feel like i don't understand the concept of paths and subpaths and what state the context is storing. I have done extensive searching for solutions to this problem but haven't found anything that works.

Here is some typical code from my symbol library:

```
function plotSymbol(ctx, symbol, h, v, width, symcolor) {
    var i;
    if (width == 0) return;

    if (symbol == Resources.PlotSymbolsEnum.SYMBOL_SQUARE) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = symcolor;
        ctx.strokeRect(h - width / 2.0, v - width / 2.0, width, width);
    }
    else if (symbol == Resources.PlotSymbolsEnum.SYMBOL_SQUAREFILLED) {
        ctx.fillStyle = symcolor;
        ctx.fillRect(h - width / 2.0, v - width / 2.0, width, width);
    }
    else if (symbol == Resources.PlotSymbolsEnum.SYMBOL_CIRCLE) {
        var x = h - width / 2;
        var y = v - width / 2;
        drawCircle(ctx, x, y, width/2, 1, symcolor, false);
    }
    else if (symbol == Resources.PlotSymbolsEnum.SYMBOL_CIRCLEFILLED) {
        var x = h - width / 2;
        var y = v - width / 2;
        drawCircle(ctx, x, y, width/2, 1, symcolor, true);
    }
    else if (symbol == Resources.PlotSymbolsEnum.SYMBOL_DIAMOND) {
        var xpoints1 = [ h, h + width / 2, h, h - width / 2 ];
        var ypoints1 = [ v - width / 2, v, v + width / 2, v ];

        ctx.strokeStyle = symcolor;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(xpoints1[0], ypoints1[0]);
        for (i = 1; i < xpoints1.length; i++) {
            ctx.lineTo(xpoints1[i], ypoints1[i]);
        }
//        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    }
    else if (symbol == Resources.PlotSymbolsEnum.SYMBOL_DIAMONDFILLED) {
        var xpoints2 = [ h, h + width / 2, h, h - width / 2 ];
        var ypoints2 = [ v - width / 2, v, v + width / 2, v ];

        ctx.fillStyle = symcolor;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(xpoints2[0], ypoints2[0]);
        for (i = 1; i < xpoints2.length; i++) {
            ctx.lineTo(xpoints2[i], ypoints2[i]);
        }

//        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    }
    else if (symbol == Resources.PlotSymbolsEnum.SYMBOL_TRIANGLE) {
        var xpoints3 = [ h - width / 2, h + width / 2, h ];
        var ypoints3 = [ v + width / 2, v + width / 2, v - width / 2 ];

        ctx.strokeStyle = symcolor;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(xpoints3[0], ypoints3[0]);
        for (i = 1; i < xpoints3.length; i++) {
            ctx.lineTo(xpoints3[i], ypoints3[i]);
        }

//        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    }
    else if (symbol == Resources.PlotSymbolsEnum.SYMBOL_TRIANGLEFILLED) {
        var xpoints3 = [ h - width / 2, h + width / 2, h ];
        var ypoints3 = [ v + width / 2, v + width / 2, v - width / 2 ];

        ctx.strokeStyle = symcolor;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(xpoints3[0], ypoints3[0]);
        for (i = 1; i < xpoints3.length; i++) {
            ctx.lineTo(xpoints3[i], ypoints3[i]);
        }

//        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    }
    else if (symbol == Resources.PlotSymbolsEnum.SYMBOL_CROSS1) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = symcolor;
        width += 1;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(h - width / 2, v);
        ctx.lineTo(h + width / 2, v);
        ctx.moveTo(h, v - width / 2);
        ctx.lineTo(h, v + width / 2);
//        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    }
    else if (symbol == Resources.PlotSymbolsEnum.SYMBOL_CROSS2) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = symcolor;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(h - width / 2, v - width / 2);
        ctx.lineTo(h + width / 2, v + width / 2);
        ctx.moveTo(h - width / 2, v + width / 2);
        ctx.lineTo(h + width / 2, v - width / 2);
//        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    }
}
```

I have commented out the closepaths because I don’t always want the shape to return to the original point. I think I put them in originally because I misunderstood what closePath() does and thought they would make drawing a symbol independent of other symbols.

And here’s how it might be called:

```
ctx.save();
ctx.rect(left, y1, width, height);
ctx.clip();
.
.
.
y = this.mMonthlyMeans[i];
y = (y - yOrigin) * yScale;
y = Math.floor(y) + 0.5;
plotSymbol(ctx, theMeanSym, this.getPlotLeft() + xCtr, y, theMeanSymSize, theMeanSymbolColor);
ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';  // this call is perhaps unnecessary in properly written code but seems to head off some problems
.
.
.
ctx.restore() // to restore the clip
```

I would greatly appreciate any advice and pointers for doing this correctly in HTML5 Canvas. It doesn't appear to be as simple as just drawing pixels into a Graphics2D object like Java,

Answer (score 0):

You should set `strokeStyle` before calling `ctx.stroke()` or `ctx.strokeXXX()`, and set `fillStyle` before `ctx.fill()` or `ctx.fillXXX()`, in each of your condition block.

you missed `strokeStyle` in `SYMBOL_DIAMONDFILLED` block and `fillStyle` in `SYMBOL_TRIANGLEFILLED` block.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found the solution. Googling about today I found a tutorial (http://eloquentjavascript.net/16_canvas.html) on drawing into the Canvas object. The author states:

> "A path can contain multiple shapes—each moveTo motion starts a new one."

This was the clue  was looking for. I have methods that draw cross and x symbols using moveTo and lineTo. This is what my cross symbol code (ported from Java) looked liked:

```
    ctx.strokeStyle = symcolor;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(h - width / 2, v);
    ctx.lineTo(h + width / 2, v);
    ctx.moveTo(h, v - width / 2);
    ctx.lineTo(h, v + width / 2);
    ctx.stroke();
```

The mistake is that internal moveTo starts a new subpath and the stroke command appears to only render the first subpath in the strokeStyle color or uses the default color. The net effect is that most symbols are drawn in the correct color but (I think) the last symbol is drawn in the default color which appears to be black.

Changing the code so that I stroke the segments separately causes all the symbols to be drawn in the correct color:

```
    ctx.strokeStyle = symcolor;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(h - width / 2, v);
    ctx.lineTo(h + width / 2, v);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(h, v - width / 2);
    ctx.lineTo(h, v + width / 2);
    ctx.stroke();
```